# can i use ":" in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, data-structures, hash

Currently i am using the "=>" for hash

```
registrationData = {
        "webhook_uri" => "http://148.251.44.168:5000"
    }

   puts make_request("webhooks","POST",registrationData)
```

But i want to use ":" instead of "=>" like the below code

```
    registrationData = {
    "webhook_uri": "http://148.251.44.168:5000"
}
```

But the above code throws error

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting =>
"webhook_uri": "http://148.251.44.168:5000"
```

but seems like api ony accepts this format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it. This syntax applies only to `Symbol` hash keys. What you can do is allow symbol-based hash as an argument to `make_request` method (or check if it isn't allowed already) - or use [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) from [`activesupport`](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) gem.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in ruby < 2.2. But starting from 2.2.0 this is actually a valid syntax:

```
2.2.0 :001 > { 'a': 'b' }
 => {:a=>"b"}
```

Which, anyway, will convert key into symbol.